# how to scroll screen in android

Tags: android, scroll

I'm learning the android. I created a simple xml screen but data is going out of screen and the screen is not scrolling. Can any body tell me how to make scrollable my phone screen?

Answer (score 6):

Put it inside a `ScrollView`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code for a fixed header and fixed footer and a scrolling body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content">
<TextView
  android:text="Header"
  android:id="@+id/textViewHeader"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
<TextView
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:text="Footer"
  android:id="@+id/textViewFooter"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
<ScrollView
  android:layout_above="@id/textViewFooter"
  android:layout_below="@id/textViewHeader"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  >
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_below="@id/textViewHeader"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView android:text="@string/about_tlh_body"
  android:id="@+id/textViewBody"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Make your Activity a ListActivity

Here is an example that implements a listView / ListActivity

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parseread-xml-data-into-android-listview/

Scroll to the bottom of the post to find the Eclipse project to see the full implementation.

You can also use a http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Answer (score 0):

Puth the whole layout inside scrollView.i.e the topmost/parent layout is scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code in your activity of AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```